# MySQL conditional Insert for checking Single-value and Multi-value keys

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, sql-insert

I have a MySQL table with Columns (id, key, value). Keys are predefined strings. As an example key can be color, height, width, etc,...values can be single-valued or multi-valued.

Ex:-

- height  and width are single value keys
- color is a multi-value key (For an object there can be multiple colors)

values for multi-value keys are stored in the database as a single string (with comma separated values)

My Problem is How can I enforce single value keys to be single-valued while inserting.

Ex:-

- For the height key and width key value must be single-valued
- For the color key value can be multi-valued

How Can I Enforce this condition while inserting? What will be the best way?

Edit :

- Single valued attributes can be String ,Int Or Boolean.
- Multi Valued attributes are Strings

Comment: Why can;t you store them in multiple rows (e.g. `(1, 'color', 'red')` and `(1, 'color', 'green')`)?

Comment: For a key all the values must be stored in a single row.It's a required condition for my case.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce this condition while inserting you can create BEFORE INSERT trigger and make your checks there. As far I understand your logic for "multi-valued" keys you can check whether they are in the database table and for "single-valued" you can check whether the value is a number.

Comment: Actually Single Valued keys can be String,Int or boolean.What will be the condition for that case ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can add a [CHECK constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html). A minimal example:

```
create table t(
  id int,
  `key` varchar(100),
  `value` varchar(100),
  check (case
      when `key` in ('width', 'height') then `value` not like '%,%'
  end = 1)
)
```

It is also possible to use `REGEXP` clause to check if numbers are in fact numbers.
[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=354e061d5c55c2a8c44e98661969f6e5)

Another improvement would be to store the values a JSON (boolean, string, number or array) then use `json_type` to check the type of value being saved.

Comment: I didn't get what you have said in the improvement.Can you please describe it more ?

Comment: You could store values as JSON e.g. `('width', '100'), ('foo', '"bar"'), ('color', '["red", "green"]')`. That is somewhat better than storing numbers as strings or storing comma separated values.

Comment: But If I do that, doing queries with keys will be hard.I guess

Comment: Yes that would require you to use json functions. Not hard though.

Comment: Thank you so much.I'm wondering , is there a do the check while inserting ? (Without defining the check when creating the table)

Comment: You check inside your application code! A very clumsy solution here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c85075ee7d375efc2fa53e49d85ed2b